# EbayApi rather then getItem use GetSellerList ( says ebay )

Tags: php, xml, soap, ebay-api

In order to retrieve the actual Variation Gallery URL for a Variant Purchased I need to call `getItem` many times.

Obviously Ebay suggest to use `getSellerList` to avoid multiple `getItem` calls; but, surprisingly, this call can't find items based on their Ebay Item number, but only filtering by SKU. That obviously retrieves nothing.

Is there any batch call to retrieve more Items by their Ebay item number and not by this non-working SKU?

Answer (score 2):

You should try calling "GetMyeBaySelling" as below it gives me all the variations and it's details as well and as you get results you can save it to an array and search for the item you want.

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$eBay->auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ActiveList>
<Sort>Title</Sort>
<IncludeNotes>FALSE</IncludeNotes>
<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$pageNo</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
</ActiveList>
<HideVariations>FALSE</HideVariations>
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Version>$eBay->api_version</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>​
EOD;
```

Comment: thank your for answering, I don't need all the variation, just the ones purchased to get the Gallery URL . Ebay gives full information on a sale, but the picture of product taken, it's umbelievable